# Trying to create wheel of divs which rotate on drag

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I'm trying to create the following using the url below.

http://fff.cmiscm.com/#!/main

So far succeeded to create the divs at load but unable to rotate on mouse drag can you please help? Here's my file below

I just need to know how the rotation can be accomplished when you click and drag mouse in circular motion. All div items inside semi circle have class .items and I'm new to animation.

Also I've added my html code as snippet file for reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#pantone {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
}

.show-pantone {
    opacity: 1!important;
    transition: opacity .5s cubic-bezier(.55, .055, .675, .19);
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s cubic-bezier(.55, .055, .675, .19);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s cubic-bezier(.55, .055, .675, .19);
    -o-transition: opacity .5s cubic-bezier(.55, .055, .675, .19)
}

.items {
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    height: 310px;
    position: absolute;
}

.item-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
 border:1px solid red;
}


#root {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 900px;
    min-height: 771px;
 //height: 645px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.item-txt {
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -90px;
    top: -310px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #bcbbc5;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: color .2s linear;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ThrowPropsPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var V=0.017453292519943295, S=951, al=900, A=110, R=1299, J=155, b=36, an=10, G=26, a=0, c=16, ao=20, f={}, p=[],y={pos:0}, az=0, U = 0, M = false;  
 f.posArr =[];
 
 
 function loadDivs(){
   for (var a = 0; a < G; a++) {
    var itemsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    itemsDiv.id = "items" + a;
    itemsDiv.className = "items";
    
    
    p[a] = {
     item: itemsDiv,
     use: 0,
     no: 0,
     click: 0,
     bg: -1
    };
    E(itemsDiv, a, p[a]);
    document.getElementById("pantone").appendChild(itemsDiv);
   }
   
   for (var i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    f.posArr[i] = {
     pos: i * an - 90,
     use: 0,
     cur: 0,
     item: null,
     no: i
    };
      
   }
   l();
  }
 
 function E(aE, aF, aC) {
        var aD = document.createElement("div");
          
        aD.className = "item-button";
        aD.setAttribute("data-id", aF);
        aE.appendChild(aD);
        $(aD).on("click", T);
        B(aC)
    }
 
 function l() {
   var aD, aB, aC;
   aD = f.posArr[0];
   aC = aD.pos;
   for (var aB = 0; aB < b; aB++) {
    aD = f.posArr[aB];
    af(aD, aC + (an * aB), aB)
   }
   aj()
  }
 
     function af(aE, aB, aD) {
   aB = aB % 360;
   if (aB < 0) {
    aB = aB + 360
   }
   aE.pos = aB;
   if (aB > 190 && aB < 350) {
    if (aE.use == 0 || aE.item == null) {
     aE.use = 1;
     var aC;
     if (aD < 18) {
      aC = o(aD + a, ao)
     } else {
      aC = o(aD - c + a, ao)
     }
     aE.cur = aC;
     aE.item = au(aD, aC)
    }
    if (aE.item != null) {
     ap(aE.item, aB)
    }
   } else {
    if (aE.use == 1) {
     aE.use = 0;
     if (aE.item != null) {
      aE.item.use = 0;
      aE.item.bg = -1;
      B(aE.item);
      aE.item = null
     }
    }
   }
  }
 
  function o(aC, aB) {
        return (aC + (aB * (Math.abs((aC / 10) | 0) + 1))) % aB
    }
 
 function T(aC) {
        if (Math.abs(az) > 10) {
            return
        }
        var aE = aC.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id") | 0,
            aB = p[aE].bg,
           
        M = true;
        U = 0;
    }
 
 function ap(aE, aG) {
        var aF = 270 - aG,
            aB = Math.abs(aF),
            aC = 100 - aB | 0,
            aH = 1 - (aB * 0.006),
            aD = Y(aG + (aF * aF * aF * aF * aF * 5e-9));
        aE.item.style["transform"] = "translate3d(" + aD.x + "px, " + aD.y + "px, 0px) rotate(" + (aG + 90) + "deg) scale(" + aH + ")";
        if (aE.click == 1) {
            aE.item.style.zIndex = 110
        } else {
            aE.item.style.zIndex = aC
        }
    }
 
 function Y(aF) {
        var aE = Math.cos(aF * V),
            aB = Math.sin(aF * V),
            aD = (aE) * al + S - A,
            aC = (aB) * al + R - J;
        return {
            x: aD,
            y: aC
        }
    }

 
 function au(aF, aE) {
        var aD, aC, aB, aG;
  var ab = 26;
        for (aC = 0; aC < ab; aC++) {
            aD = p[aC];
            if (aD.use == 0) {
                aD.use = 1;
                aD.no = aF;
                aD.bg = aE;
                //aB = ConfigModel.imgArr[aE] + "_c.png";
                //aG = ConfigModel.configArr[aE].poster;
                aD.item.style.border = "1px solid red";
    /*aD.item.style.background = aG.itemcolor + " url(" + aB + ") no-repeat";
                g[aC].innerHTML = (aG.title).toLowerCase();
                n[aC].innerHTML = aG.date;*/
                return aD
            }
        }
    }
 
 
 function aj() {
        var aB = 0.8;
  
  //CMDetect.isDevice == false
        if (false) {
            y.pos = 0;
            aB = 1.2
        } else {
            y.pos = 320
        }
        TweenLite.to(y, 2, {
            pos: -90,
            ease: Back.easeOut,
            easeParams: [aB],
            onUpdate: ax,
            onUpdateParams: [0]
            //onComplete: q
        });
        document.getElementById("pantone").className = "chand show-pantone"
    }
 
 function ax(aD) {
        var aC = y.pos,
            aE, aB;
        for (aB = 0; aB < b; aB++) {
            aE = f.posArr[aB];
            af(aE, aC - (an * (aD - aB)), aB)
        }
    }
 
 function B(aB) {
        aB.item.style["transform"] = "translate3d(-500px, -500px, 0px) rotate(0deg)"
    }
 
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  loadDivs();
  

 });



</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root">
 <div id="pantone" class="show-pantone">
  <div id="pantone-loading" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></div>  
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: what works for you? Initial loading of divs as per the link or rotation of divs in circular motion on mouse click and drag?

Comment: Both work fine here

Comment: Are you clicking the link at the top or running the code snippet? I'm trying to recreate the link at top and I need to add rotation part in my code snippet.